# joined the group which is permission granted, but still get 'permission denied'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, centos, devops

Why is the group member has no rights to list the directory?

```
ll /var/www
```

> drwxrwSr--   4  www-data  www-data  4096  /var/www/html

the default html dir is owned by www-data uid and www-data gid, with umask 764.

I'm logged in with user B, and join in group www-data with command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data B
```

but sill get 'Permission Denied', even has no permission to list the dir.

```
ll /var/www/html
```

> d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./ d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../

Comment: Did you relogin user B or join group with`newgrp` after adding to `www-data`? What `id` says? And what permissions of `/var/www` itself?

Comment: I relogined user B and `id B` said www-data group is in the joined group list
`ls /var`   shows the owner of /var/www is www-data:www-data too.

Comment: What does "with umask 764" mean? Is it permission bits of the directory or user's file mode creation mask? What `stat /var/www /var/www/html` says?

Comment: `stat /var/www/html` said:

Access: (2764/drwxrw-r--) Uid: (33/www-data) Gid: (33/www-data)
I changed the permission mask from 764 to 774 solved the problem, seems like both "LS" command and create new file need the x permission bit.

Comment: Yes, 'execute' bit for directories means 'search' permission. If it is not set, files and subdirectories cannot be accessed.